# Magento 2.1.7 - how to include js on just the homepage

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, home-page

I'm trying to add a counter to my Magento homepage that only starts counting when it's visible on the screen. I have got the counter to work with jquery.appear.js and now want to implement it on my Magento 2.1.7 site. I will place all of this code in a custom block and add it to the homepage.

```
<div id="counters">
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                [SMILEY IMG]<br><span class="counter" data-count="100"></span><span>%</span><br>Satisfaction
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery.appear.js"></script>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
        $('#counters').appear(function() {
            $('.counter').each(function() {
              var $this = $(this),
              countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
              $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
                countNum: countTo
            },
        {
            duration: 5000,
            easing:'linear',
            step: function() {
                $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
            },
            complete: function() {
            $this.text(this.countNum);
        }
      });  
    });
});
```

});

How do I include the jquery.appear.js into my current theme where it will only be included on the home page and none of the other pages? I figure that it should be added after jquery.

The other solutions I have come across here all include it on all pages across the site.  I want to limit it just to the homepage.

I hope the solution is as easy as modifying a local.xml file in one of my  app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/ folders to add this new js file.

```
<layout>
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.appear-min.js</name></action>
    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

Thanks in advance.

**[UPDATE]**

As per @Sohel Rana, I have added the jquery.appear.js into /Vendor_ThemeName/view/frontend/web/js/ and I will add the following code into a custom block.

```
<script>
    require(['jquery', 'Smartwave_porto_child/js/jquery.appear', 'domReady!'], function($, jqueryAppear){

        jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
            $('#counters').appear(function() {

                $('.counter').each(function() {
                  var $this = $(this),
                      countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

                  $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
                    countNum: countTo
                  },
                  {
                    duration: 5000,
                    easing:'linear',
                    step: function() {
                      $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                      $this.text(this.countNum);
                    }

                  });  
                });
            });
        });     
    });
</script>
```

Is this correct?

I want it to only be included on the homepage but it seems like this will make it available sitewide.

I read in another post that they also had to include it in their requirejs-config.js file, does this not need that step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use cms_index_index.xml.

VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="testForm" template="VendorName_ModuleName::form.phtml" cacheable="false">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now create form.phtml under templates directory and added your code here.

**[Update]**

You can add JS following way. But always avoid to add js directly, try to use requirejs for loading js.

VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="VendorName_ModuleName::jquery.appear.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

**Recommend:** In your case add js file under VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js, then added following sample code into phtml

```
<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'VendorName_ModuleName/js/jquery.appear-min'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            jqueryAppear
        ) {
            // custom code here
        });
</script>
```

Comment: The code to run the counter will be included as a block on the homepage. I will edit my post to explain that. I just want include the jquery.appear.js on the homepage. Will this work for that?

Comment: yes agreed wont directly include the js file.  however, wont your update of using VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js include the js on every page or how can i just limit it to the homepage?

Comment: VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml - load only homepage

Comment: ok thanks let me try it out.  Can I just add it to the custom block that I am adding to my homepage?.

Comment: Yes, try first one that's add a simple block.

Comment: if i use the simple block, wont it will include the js on every page of the site in the merged js file instead of just including it on the home page alone?

Comment: thank you! it worked. however, will this only load the js file on the homepage or will it load it across the whole site?

Comment: That works for referencing a js in a module. Is it possible to reference it in the theme directory?