# How to create a custom Slider in magento2 with out using any third party modules-Magento2

Tags: magento2, slider, banner-slider, custompage

I have created a custom page using route and controller.I have some image paths then how can i create slider for using these images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using sick slider https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

place slick.min.js in app/design/frontend/[You Design Dir]/[Theme Name]/web/js/slick.min.js
then use .slick on the list

```
<ol id="slider">
   <div class="image-div">
   <div class="image-div">
   <div class="image-div">
   <div class="image-div">
</ol>
```

```
$('#slider').slick({
            centerMode: false,
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 4,
            dots: false,
            autoplay: false,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 1360,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 3,
                        infinite: true,
                        slidesToScroll: 1,
                        arrows: false,
                        dots: true,
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 1025,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 2,
                        infinite: true,
                        slidesToScroll: 1,
                        arrows: false,
                        dots: true,
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 769,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 1,
                        infinite: true,
                        slidesToScroll: 1,
                        arrows: false,
                        dots: true,
                        variableWidth: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 560,
                    settings: "unslick"
                }
            ]
        });
```

In this example i have used slick sliders, I have updated the break points fofr responsive view of slider and for a particular break point i have removed the slider using unslick property

Comment: This is useful.can you please provide slick.min.js refrence.for adding slick.min.js  in design folder.

Comment: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick here it is